# Importing external methods in Composition API (Vue 3, Nuxt 3)

Tags: methods, import, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxt3

I have a really simple question, but I don't find anywhere the answer.

Regarding the cases where before we could import a function (from a library or one handmade function from utils or other folder) inside a component made in Vue 2, just putting the name of the imported function inside of the methods section, separated by a comma by the others.

Now in Vue 3, in the Composition API, I don't see the place to do the equivalent.

Or can I just assume this imported function will work even if not declared inside the setup function or in the script setup ?

Maybe it is just necessary to return it in the setup function without declaring it? Any idea about this?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Composition API is a lot more like standard JavaScript.  Using `<script setup>` you just import and call as needed.  Using `setup()` function you do the same but anything from script used in template needs to be returned.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I know, so in this case, how would you return a function that is defined in the above import (imported from other file) ?
thank you

Comment: For example, something like this: 
import { slugifyText } from '~/utils/text'

Comment: script setup is recommended.  it's easier, less boilerplate code, and you don't have a return statement to worry about.  if you want to use the setup function, it's in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup#basic-usage) that you return an object with everything you want to use in the template as object properties. For example, `return { slugifyText }`